# Chrome doesn't play mp4 after I install quicktime

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, mp4

I'm designing a web page for old browsers that don't support `<video>`. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="embedOnly">
    <embed src="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/movie.mp4" />
</div>

<div id="objectOnly">
    <object data="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/movie.mp4"></object>
</div>

<div id="embedInObject">
    <object data="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/movie.mp4">
        <embed src="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/movie.mp4">
    </object>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly in Chrome. But when I test with Firefox, it asks me to install `QuickTime 7`. After I install `QuickTime 7`, Chrome suddenly can't play any video in the three tags. See the following pic.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a Flash fallback rather than a QuickTime fallback (Flash has a better adoption rate on old browsers).

You can find an example [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#example) or [here](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody). You need to include the flash fallback within the video tag (older browsers that do not know about the video tag will skip to the flash object tag)

If you need an open source flash player have a look at Strobe from [OSMF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smp.adobe/files/).

For your issue with QuickTime it is probably some settings in Chrome, either try to troubleshoot your plugin settings or simply uninstall QuickTime 7 from your PC.

Tell us if it works for you.

Comment: To uninstall QuickTime or disable Chrome QuickTime plugin indeed solves the problem. But I was actually asking why that happened to Chrome. QuickTime can play `mp4` on my desktop, it just fails in Chrome browser. Are QuickTime and Chrome incompatible?

Comment: it should work in Chrome. I would suggest you use the recommended object/embed code for Quicktime from Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-2-HTMLScripting). If it still does not work try to reinstall Quicktime and/or Chrome.